# time stamps mysql data base

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have some data with time stamps as follows

```
11:00:00  23
11:03:25  24
12:05:27  27
13:23:00  20
.
.
.
```

I want to keep this data in to mysql data base. But while reading the data from data base,

I will ask value for some specific time and I should get it as follows.

- if asked for `11:00:00`,  I should get value  `23`
- if asked for `11:01:00`,  I should get value  `23`
- if asked for `12:30:00`,  I should get value  `27`

and so on.

So even though the middle entries are not there, I should get the earlier time stamps value.

So how to Insert/read/design the mysql table for this purpose. Please help.

Comment: Return a single row or all rows below that time?

Answer (score 1):

```
select `value` from table_name
 where `time` <= ?
 order by `time` desc
 -- fetch only 1 record
 limit 1 -- else comment this to fetch all
```

Use your input value in placeholder.